# How to search public Maven/Ivy repositories for a particular class?

Tags: maven, ivy

There are web sites like http://mvnrepository.com/ letting to search for an "artifact" and giving a definition I can add to my project for a library to be downloaded automatically from a public repository.

But this particular example (mvnrepository.com) (the only working I know actually) is by-definition limited to "search by group, artifact or description" while I would like to search by a class full name. For example I'd like to enter `org.apache.commons.lang.NotImplementedException` to get `<dependency org="commons-lang" name="commons-lang" rev="2.6"/>` (or alike) as the answer. Is there a facility for this?

Comment: I usually start at jarfinder.com.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

<del>The answer of  [@khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10057208/1288294) is straight and correct, but if you possibly want to search over few additional public Maven repos (like JBoss), not only Maven Central, I recommend using http://grepcode.com.</del>

**EDIT:** Unfortunately it seems http://grepcode.com, I used to strongly recommend for such a stuff, is dead now. Currently I don't know a better place than https://search.maven.org, already answered by [@khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10057208/1288294).

Comment: While it could be handy sometimes, right now indexed jars in GrepCode are quite outdated

Comment: Getting `HTTP 503 Service Unavailable` for grepcode.com

Comment: Yep, it seems Grepcode is dead (RIP - I used that site a LOT), so hope the community can find a new website for doing this

Answer (score 47):

If you like to search for Classes you should use http://search.maven.org and click on "Advanced search"...This is for Maven Central

Comment: That "advanced search" gave me 470 artifacts for one standard class :-( Is there a less advanced but more usable search engine?

Comment: You can use something like this in a search box:
   v:"2.6.4" c:"com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer"

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to try all the search engines. Now I've lost hours thinking of how to upload an artifact, while it turned out to be already present in the repo. This is `junit-addons`, which is both *groupId* and *artifactId*, as can be verified in [pom](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=junit-addons/junit-addons/1.4/junit-addons-1.4.pom). My attempts:

1. http://mvnrepository.com - no
2. http://search.maven.org - **yes**
3. http://grepcode.com - no
4. http://jarfinder.com - yes, but only a direct download, not for maven

I am a maven newbie, so I cannot state that the second link is the best. Although tt was the only helpful in my case.

Comment: The jarfinder domain is now for sale.

Answer (score 4):

https://javalibs.com/ is a good online site to search maven repos.

Comment at Apr. 17th 2022: 
It seems this site can't be opened any more.

Answer (score 2):

One more search engine: [JAR-Download.com](https://jar-download.com/):

- The class search page: [Search classes in the Maven repository](https://jar-download.com/maven-repository-class-search.php).
- For the sake of reference, the **archived** search page: [Search classes in the Maven repository](http://web.archive.org/web/20210422130353/https://jar-download.com/maven-repository-class-search.php).

Comment: this answer provides the simplest solution for the request