# Which of the listed .jar contains class 'com.twitter.finagle.stats.ExceptionStatsHandler'?

Tags: java, scala, maven, twitter, finagle

I have to use `Finagle 6.35.0` for `Scala 2.11` as a dependency.

I made my project dependent on

1. `finagle-core_2.11-6.35.0.jar`
2. `finagle-stats_2.11-6.35.0.jar`.

Error what I got:
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.twitter.finagle.stats.ExceptionStatsHandler`.

I expected this class to be in one of these jars. However none of these jars contains `ExceptionStatsHandler` which is a little bit surprising for me. I have searched for it in some other finagle `.jars` like for example `finagle-commons-stats_2.11-6.35.0.jar` but without success.

Could you tell me in which finagle dependency (`.jar`) I could find `com.twitter.finagle.stats.ExceptionStatsHandler`? Maybe it should be in one of previously mentioned ones but I use improper library version?

I am talking about `.jars` instead of maven or gradle dependencies because my project is a J-boss module and I have to manually add `.jars` as dependencies.

Comment: You should be able to retrieve the jar with this maven dependency : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twitter/util-stats

Comment: To find the jar, go to [Central](https://search.maven.org/) and search for `fc:com.twitter.finagle.stats.ExceptionStatsHandler` (full classname).

Comment: @Arnaud Thanks. It is there. Write your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @chrylis Your advice works as well. I will use it in the future in similar cases. Btw. I  usually use `mvnrepository.com` instead of `search.maven.org`, maybe there is also similar way to search for dependency containing specified class?

Comment: `search.maven.org` actually searches the Maven central repository, which is where maven looks for dependencies by default.

Comment: @luke It's entirely likely that it's there, but I'm not familiar with the query syntax.

Comment: @chrylis I made a small research. Probably there is no such option on mvnrepository.com. I tried to find some documentation about searching on this website. Without success. I also found this question and answer [How to search public Maven/Ivy repositories for a particular class?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12550846/1673775). So seemingly [jar-download.com](https://jar-download.com/maven-repository-class-search.php) and [search.maven.org](https://search.maven.org) are better in this particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching for your class name we can find :

[Source code: Class ExceptionStatsHandler.scala part of util-stats_2.12 version 18.1.0](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.twitter/util-stats_2.12/18.1.0/source-code/com/twitter/finagle/stats/ExceptionStatsHandler.scala)

With this information, we can find the according maven dependency : [Utilities Stats](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twitter/util-stats)

@chrylis also suggests a good way to search for a particular class in the Maven repository :

> To find the jar, go to [Central](https://search.maven.org/) and search for
>   fc:com.twitter.finagle.stats.ExceptionStatsHandler (full classname).